# Repairing Windows 7 boot after Ubuntu 10.10 install

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I've read various threads on this after googling, including one on this site.

I had Windows 7 installed on an SSD.  I wanted to try Ubuntu so I created a partition for it on the SSD and booted with the live CD to install Ubuntu.  Went through the install and somehow Ubuntu carved out another partition on the SSD rather than using the one I had already created.  Windows 7 would then not boot but Ubuntu would.

I booted with my 7 cd and ran the automatic startup repair, it didn't find any problems.  I then ran the bootsect command on the drive with 7.  It said it repaired the bootmgr but Windows still would not boot and now Ubuntu won't either.

I read somewhere else that it may be due to the partition that 7 was on being changed during the install.  I don't care about the Ubuntu installation but I don't want to lose the 7 install, can I delete the ubuntu partition through booting with the 7 cd?  Will that do any good?

Thank you all!  I'm stumped even though I've done startup repairs before, just not after Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem.

Provided you have a windows recovery disk / access to the recovery console, you can use the bootrec program to recover your boot. I fixed mine using the `/FixMbr` flag:

`bootrec.exe /FixMbr`

more info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Answer (score 0):

I've had to run it a couple times before it actually DID work.. the first time it reported it fixed the MBR, but ran it again, and viola, it was fixed.